Backpack laravel multiple file upload - preview/download is not working
I am trying to upload/view multiple files with Backpack:5.x
Code for the file upload
Controller

 $this->crud->addfield([
            'name'    => 'files',
            'label'   => 'Files',
            'upload'    => true,
            'type'    => 'upload_multiple',
        ]);

Model

public function setFilesAttribute($value)
    {
        $attribute_name = "files";
        $disk = "uploads";
        $destination_path = "notes";

        $this->uploadMultipleFilesToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
    }

config/filessystems.php

'uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads',
            'root' => public_path('uploads'),
        ],


Problem 1:
Files saved in public/uploads/notes directory but when I edit an item, the url for the uploaded file is www.test.com/notes/file.txt getting 404(missing the /**uploads**/notes/file.txt).
Problem 2: When I am trying to add in list view, I am getting this error -
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: /vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/columns/upload_multiple.blade.php)
$this->crud->addColumn([
            'name'    => 'files',
            'label'   => 'Files',
            'type'    => 'upload_multiple',
        ]);


Answered: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/5546#issuecomment-2191643268
